# Join customer_entity snd catalog_product_entity by custom attribute

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel, join-table

I use Magento 2 I need to display some data from customer and product in admin grid panel and I wonder how to join catalog_product_entity table with customer_entity. I added custom attribute to product which stores customer entity_id. I want use it for grid filterSearch fulltext.

Thank you for advice.